# find referances to an eclipse project element in a project hierarchy

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a web project in eclipse. I am looking for some way to find references to 
a particular file (.js,.css,.html.....).

I want to know that where this particular file is used.
the same functionality ctrl+shift+g

but unfortunately this shortcut only works for keywords(like java classes or methods)

Is there any plugin available for doing this in eclipse ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the normal search dialog, Ctrl+H? Enter the filename as the text.

It's 'easier' for the Java search to work, as Eclipse knows where to look (.java files and .class files) and what to look for (occurences of the class in the Abstract Syntax Tree or bytecode).

For a generic file search that has 'file format knowledge', it needs to know how to parse each file it's looking in.

So the most general way of doing this is a simple text search using Ctrl+H.